# Calculation in multiple Html tables on a single page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to perform calculations at the end of every table (on a footer) in a single page.

Suppose I have two tables and I want to perform calculations on a Total Amount column.

How can I do that using Jquery and Javascript?

There might be more than two tables so please be sure it works on multiple tables on a single page.

These values in HTML table are gained using for loop in Django.

This image contains 2 HTML tables and I want calculations on both table on a total amount column.

[image]

```
<div class="row">
<div class="table-responsive col-md-6">

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive-xl">
    <caption style="caption-side:top; text-align: center;"><h3>Income</h3></caption>
    <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        {#  <th>S No.</th>#}
            <th>Particulars</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Total Amount</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for item in all_profit %}
    {% if item.category.under == "Income" %}
        <tr>
        {#  <td>{{  }}&nbsp;</td>#}
            <td>{{item.category}}</td>
            <td>{{item.category.desc}}</td>
            <td>{{ item.balance }}&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
            <tfoot>
        <tr class="totalColumn">
            <td style="visibility:hidden;"></td>
            <td>Total:</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Just add a class to each footer that contains your value and perform your calculations on them after the tables are done rendering.

Comment: would you please post your tables html

Comment: sure i updated my ques and post the table code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set same class for each income item's total amount then get them with Jquery and convert them to Int and calculate total.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.income-amount').each(function(i, obj) {
    total += parseInt($(obj).text());
  });
  $('#income-total').text(total.toFixed(1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="table-responsive col-md-6">

    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive-xl">
      <caption style="caption-side:top; text-align: center;">
        <h3>Income</h3>
      </caption>
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th>S No.</th>
          <th>Particulars</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Total Amount</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1&nbsp;</td>
          <td>A</td>
          <td> </td>
          <td class='income-amount'>2000.0&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1&nbsp;</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td> </td>
          <td class='income-amount'>1400.0&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr class="totalColumn">
          <td style="visibility:hidden;"></td>
          <td id='income-total'>Total:</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hey @barzin.A what if i want to create a new table and put all the multiple table income values in a single column just by adding variables using jquery. How??